# Replace value in one column with average of 7 columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv, missing-data

I have a dataframe containing hospital data. In one of my attribute i have a value of '-1' which i want to replace with the average value of 7 columns ahead it.
[image]

All tuples having Rating.Overall as '-1', this value should be replaced with the average of values from the columns ahead i.e. Rating.Mortality, Rating.Safety, Rating.Readmission etc., but i am unable to generate the code for that.

Comment: post a valid and testable dataframe fragmment

Answer (score 0):

What you would want to do is construct a sub-dataframe with just the columns you want to take an average over and then use `.mean(axis=1)`, which will mean across the columns instead of the rows. Take a look at the docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html

So overall: `df['my_new_column'] = df[['col_1', 'col_2', ... , 'col_n']].mean(axis=1)`

Edit: To only do this for rows with -1, filter the final dataframe on that query before assignment:

```
df[df['my_col'] == -1, 'my_col'] = df[['col_1', 'col_2', ... , 'col_n']].mean(axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks, but i am getting an error as TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'

Comment: this is the code i typed 
df[df['Rating.Overall'] == -1, 'Rating.Overall'] = df[['Rating.Mortality',
'Rating.Safety',
'Rating.Readmission',
'Rating.Experience',
'Rating.Effectiveness',
'Rating.Timeliness',
'Rating.Imaging' ]].mean(axis=1)